# The min-length of input is not working properly in this code

Tags: javascript, html

The min-length of input is not working properly in this code. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Why is this? I tried to input 3 characters using the 'if' statement of JavaScript, but I want to make an error message appear in the input window of html if I input less than 3 characters. Why doesn't the attribute value of the html input tag work properly?

```js
const numberOfPeople = document.querySelector(".number-of-people");
const previousWord = document.querySelector(".previous-word");
const inputWord = document.querySelector("#input-word");
const submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-button");

let number = parseInt(prompt("How many people are participating in the game?"));
let word;
let flag = true;
let flag2 = true;

(function() {
    while (flag) {
        flag = false;
        if(number) {
            numberOfPeople.textContent = number;
            
            const onClickSubmitButton = (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                word = inputWord.value;
                
                if (inputWord.value.length < 3) {
                    alert("Please enter 3 characters.")
                } else if ((previousWord.textContent === "") || (previousWord.textContent[previousWord.textContent.length - 1] === word[0])) {
                    previousWord.textContent = word;
                    inputWord.value = "";
                    inputWord.focus();
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    alert("GAME_OVER");
                    inputWord.value = "";
                    previousWord.textContent = "";
                    numberOfPeople.textContent = "";
                    number = null;
                    submitButton.removeEventListener("click", onClickSubmitButton);
                    return;
                }
            }

            submitButton.addEventListener("click", onClickSubmitButton);
        } else {
            number = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number."));
            if (number && flag2) {
                numberOfPeople.textContent = number;
                flag = true;
                flag2 = false;
            }
        }
    }
})()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>word-chain game</title>
    <script src="js/word-chain_game.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="word-chain__wrapper">
        <h4>number-of-people : <span class="number-of-people"></span></h4>
        <h4>previous-word : <span class="previous-word"></span></h4>
        <form>
            <label for="input-word">enter a word</label>
            <input name="input-word" id="input-word" type="text" required minlength="3" maxlength="3" placeholder="Please enter a word."> <!-- This code is not working properly. -->
            <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="input"></input>
        </form>
        <h4></h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing tag or use a self closing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply style on input based on the `required` `minlength` attribute or you can attach an invalid event handler on input.

```
input:invalid{
 color:red;
 border-color:red;
}
```

```
<input type="text" oninvalid="alert('Please enter atleast 3 charcater in name field');"  required minlength="3">
```

Comment: The intention I have asked is to do it without using JavaScript. Thank you.